# Is it (`?:`) typescript ternary operator

Tags: typescript

I saw the code below in a TypeScript example:

```js
export interface EjectTaskOptions extends BuildOptions {
  force?: boolean;
  app?: string;
}
```

What does `?:` mean?
Is it a ternary operator (with only false condition) or something else?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

Comment: the `?` is used for Optional Properties in an interface.  http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

Comment: to make fields optional in typescript

Comment: https://www.xplatform.rocks/2016/01/07/angular2-quicky-elvis-in-tha-house/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `?` operator indicate that the property can be `nullable` / optional. It just means that the compilator will not throw an error if you do not implement this property in your implementation.

Comment: same as in `.NET`

Comment: Except that .NET also has a null-coalescing ?? operator. @mihail

Comment: Nullable/optional are *not* the same thing. Read more here:
https://medium.com/@angela.amarapala/understanding-the-usage-of-optional-and-nullable-in-typescript-826c1754df3

Answer (score 17):

You can use ?? operator!

```
const test: string = null;

console.log(test ?? 'none');
```

This will print 'none' because test is null. If there is a value for test, it will print that. You can try that here [playground typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/)

Answer (score 9):

- Your code is `nullable` variable declaration

But the symbol of `?:` using from  `Elvis operator`

It Code looks like

```
let displayName = user.name ?: "";
```

> And it's not available in typescript/javascript/angular and essentially the same as ||

More details : [Comparison of Ternary operator, Elvis operator, safe Navigation Operator and logical OR operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046927/comparison-of-ternary-operator-elvis-operator-safe-navigation-operator-and-log/44047139#44047139)

Answer (score 4):

The Elvis operator is only available for the . not for other dereference operators like [].

As a workaround use

```
{{ data?.record ? data.record['name/first'] : null}}
```

Comment: https://www.xplatform.rocks/2016/01/07/angular2-quicky-elvis-in-tha-house/